# Consulta sql separado por espaço

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte consulta sql:

```html
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT dia, GROUP_CONCAT(hora) FROM marcacoes WHERE colaborador_id = {$colaborador_id} GROUP BY dia ");
```

O resultado fica:

07:30:00,12:00:00,13:30:00,17:00:00

Como faço para tirar a vírgula separar por espaço?

ex:
07:30:00  12:00:00  13:30:00 17:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na função [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), defina o delimitador com a palavra chave `SEPARATOR`.

Escopo

```
GROUP_CONCAT(string SEPARATOR 'delimitador')
```

Exemplo completo:

```
$sql= mysql_query("SELECT dia, GROUP_CONCAT(hora, SEPARATOR ' ') FROM marcacoes WHERE colaborador_id = {$colaborador_id} GROUP BY dia ");
```